# How to generalize the pattern matching search from a file using range operator in Perl

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $kw1 = 'Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)';
my $kw2 = 'CSeq: 3 REGISTER';

my $instance_counter;
my @first;
my @next;
my $myfile = "Input.txt";
open my $out_file1, '>', 'hello1.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out_file2, '>', 'hello2.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out_file3, '>', 'hello3.txt' or die "$!";

open DATA, $myfile or die "Can't open file: $!";

while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        ++$instance_counter if 1 == $match;

        if (1 == $instance_counter) {
          print $out_file1 $_;
        } 
        elsif (2 == $instance_counter){
        print $out_file2 $_;
        }
        else {
           print $out_file3 $_;
        }


    }

}
```

My above program Is outputting the each pattern matching between $kw1 and $kw2 to a separate text file. Is there any Idea where I can generalize my search for such Instances (i.e. no of matching patterns) automatically and generating the output text files accordingly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. Open the file on entering the instance, use the counter as part of the name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;    

my $kw1 = 'Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)';
my $kw2 = 'CSeq: 3 REGISTER';

my $instance_counter;
my $out;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my $match = (/\Q$kw1/ .. /\Q$kw2/)) {
        if (1 == $match) {
            ++$instance_counter;
            undef $out;
            open $out, '>', "output_$instance_counter" or die $!;
        }

        print {$out} $_;
    }
}
undef $out;

__DATA__
...
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
1
2
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
...
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
a
b
c
d
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
...
Session Initiation Protocol (REGISTER)
X
Y
Z
CSeq: 3 REGISTER
...
```